# How should I inherit 1-1 variable from 2 different classes in Java?

Tags: java

Telecommunication company:

```
abstract class BasicContract{
    private int minute_price;
    private int SMS_price;
}

abstract class FreeSMS extends BasicContract{
    private int free_sms; 
}

abstract class Internet extends BasicContract{
    private int usable_net;
}
```

There are going to have different type of packages people can buy. There are contracts where client can:

-TALK and SEND SMS

```
class OldStyle extends BasicContract{
    ...
}
```

-TALK, SEND SMS and have a number of FREE SMS can send

```
class NeedSMS extends FreeSMS{
    ...
}
```

-TALK, SEND SMS and have internet

```
class NeedInternet extends Internet{
    ...
}
```

And I want a contract what includes TALK, SEND SMS, have FREE SMS and can INTERNET.

In C++ it would be:

```
class NeedSMSAndInternet: public FreeSMS, public Internet{
    ...
}
```

How am I supposed to do this in Java? As I saw interfaces can not have variables, only methods and in Java you do not have multiple parental classes...

Comment: Compose a class that accepts both rather than extending. You should prefer composition over inheritance chains in Java.

Comment: You should not think in terms of inherited fields, but inherited methods, and those can be defined in interfaces, e.g. `getSmsPrice()`, `setSmsPrice(double price)` etc.

Comment: Is this homework? Because you shouldn't really be doing this at all. You don't want to have to rewrite code every time they add a new plan. OO inheritance in the real world is used for fixed computer abstractions like sockets, GUI elements, I/O streams, &c. Not for customers or employees or products, and certainly not to express their various and changing roles and content.